# When and how are sync events fired in service workers?

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm having some issues regarding how and when sync events are fired. Is this something that is caused by the user doing some sort of input? I seemed to find stuff on Google's dev docs about sync events firing when you have internet again (if you lose the internet). Is this the case for desktop? Or is it just for mobile?

Comment: What kind of "sync events" do you mean?